# React HashRouter not rendering other paths, only Rendering root component '/'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash, react-router-dom

My Setup:

**routes.js**

```
const Router = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={ Dashboard } />
    <Route path="/somepath" component={ SomePath } />
  </Switch>
);
```

**index.js**

```
<HashRouter>
  <App />
</HashRouter>
```

**app.js:**

```
lass App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-app">
        <Header />
        <div className="page__container">
          <Router />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Issue is, when I navigate to `localhost/#/` rootpath, it is correctly rendering Dashboard component as mentioned in `routes.js` file. But When I naviagte to `localhost/#/somepath`, it not rendering component for somepath, it is stil rendering `/` Component.

Even in `React Devtool` it shows `<Route path="/">` is loaded, not `<Route path="/somepath">`

Comment: try `exact` like this `<Route  exact path="/somepath" component={ SomePath } />`

Comment: Thanks @Isa4299, I found the same, that is why deleted the question. Do you know if I can make dynamic route in hashrouter? Like "somepath:optionalParam"?

Comment: yeah you can do like this. `<Route exact path="/somepath/:optionalParam" component={ SomePath } />`

Comment: Got it working with: `path="/somepath/:optionalParam"`. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to add `exact` to match the path. add `exact` prop to `Route`

```
<Route exact path="/somepath" component={ SomePath } />
```